# Moving OpenLDAP to new server -- getting olcBackend error

Tags: openldap

I'm finally moving from RHEL 7 to 8. I have a new 8.6 installation and I've compiled OpenLDAP 2.5.13 and done the basic setup. As I'm moving from an existing OpenLDAP instance, I exported my LDAP settings on the old server. This new OpenLDAP uses mdb instead of hdb so I changed all instances of that in the exported ldif file.

I've deleted everything in /etc/openldap/slapd.d/. When I run
`slapadd -n 0 -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d -l configbackup.conf -d 64`
I get this

```
config_back_db_open: No explicit ACL for back-config configured. Using hardcoded default
olcBackend: value #0: <olcBackend> failed init (mdb)!
slapadd: could not add entry dn="olcBackend={0}mdb,cn=config" (line=609): <olcBackend> failed init
```

Here're the contents of configbackup.conf:

```
dn: cn=config
objectClass: olcGlobal
cn: config
olcArgsFile: /var/run/openldap/slapd.args
olcPidFile: /var/run/openldap/slapd.pid
olcTLSCACertificatePath: /etc/openldap/certs
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/openldap/certs/1d40117d24e9b169.pem
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/openldap/certs/yln.key
olcToolThreads: 1
structuralObjectClass: olcGlobal
entryUUID: 940013a0-3521-1034-9ed9-875b6f3874a7
creatorsName: cn=config
createTimestamp: 20150120185459Z
olcLogLevel: 0
entryCSN: 20220824150941.487221Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
modifyTimestamp: 20220824150941Z

dn: cn=schema,cn=config
objectClass: olcSchemaConfig
cn: schema
structuralObjectClass: olcSchemaConfig
entryUUID: 94003cfe-3521-1034-9edc-875b6f3874a7
creatorsName: cn=config
createTimestamp: 20150120185459Z
entryCSN: 20150120185459.719049Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=config
modifyTimestamp: 20150120185459Z

dn: cn={0}core,cn=schema,cn=config
objectClass: olcSchemaConfig
cn: {0}core
olcAttributeTypes: {0}( 2.5.4.2 NAME 'knowledgeInformation' DESC 'RFC2256: k
 nowledge information' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.
 121.1.15{32768} )

<following olcAttributeTypes deleted to fit character limit>

olcObjectClasses: {0}( 2.5.6.2 NAME 'country' DESC 'RFC2256: a country' SUP
 top STRUCTURAL MUST c MAY ( searchGuide $ description ) )
olcObjectClasses: {1}( 2.5.6.3 NAME 'locality' DESC 'RFC2256: a locality' SU
 P top STRUCTURAL MAY ( street $ seeAlso $ searchGuide $ st $ l $ descriptio
 n ) )
olcObjectClasses: {2}( 2.5.6.4 NAME 'organization' DESC 'RFC2256: an organiz
 ation' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST o MAY ( userPassword $ searchGuide $ seeAlso
  $ businessCategory $ x121Address $ registeredAddress $ destinationIndicato
 r $ preferredDeliveryMethod $ telexNumber $ teletexTerminalIdentifier $ tel
 ephoneNumber $ internationaliSDNNumber $  facsimileTelephoneNumber $ street
  $ postOfficeBox $ postalCode $ postalAddress $ physicalDeliveryOfficeName
 $ st $ l $ description ) )
olcObjectClasses: {3}( 2.5.6.5 NAME 'organizationalUnit' DESC 'RFC2256: an o
 rganizational unit' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST ou MAY ( userPassword $ searchG
 uide $ seeAlso $ businessCategory $ x121Address $ registeredAddress $ desti
 nationIndicator $ preferredDeliveryMethod $ telexNumber $ teletexTerminalId
 entifier $ telephoneNumber $ internationaliSDNNumber $ facsimileTelephoneNu
 mber $ street $ postOfficeBox $ postalCode $ postalAddress $ physicalDelive
 ryOfficeName $ st $ l $ description ) )
olcObjectClasses: {4}( 2.5.6.6 NAME 'person' DESC 'RFC2256: a person' SUP to
 p STRUCTURAL MUST ( sn $ cn ) MAY ( userPassword $ telephoneNumber $ seeAls
 o $ description ) )
olcObjectClasses: {5}( 2.5.6.7 NAME 'organizationalPerson' DESC 'RFC2256: an
  organizational person' SUP person STRUCTURAL MAY ( title $ x121Address $ r
 egisteredAddress $ destinationIndicator $ preferredDeliveryMethod $ telexNu
 mber $ teletexTerminalIdentifier $ telephoneNumber $ internationaliSDNNumbe
 r $  facsimileTelephoneNumber $ street $ postOfficeBox $ postalCode $ posta
 lAddress $ physicalDeliveryOfficeName $ ou $ st $ l ) )
olcObjectClasses: {6}( 2.5.6.8 NAME 'organizationalRole' DESC 'RFC2256: an o
 rganizational role' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST cn MAY ( x121Address $ register
 edAddress $ destinationIndicator $ preferredDeliveryMethod $ telexNumber $
 teletexTerminalIdentifier $ telephoneNumber $ internationaliSDNNumber $ fac
 simileTelephoneNumber $ seeAlso $ roleOccupant $ preferredDeliveryMethod $
 street $ postOfficeBox $ postalCode $ postalAddress $ physicalDeliveryOffic
 eName $ ou $ st $ l $ description ) )
olcObjectClasses: {7}( 2.5.6.9 NAME 'groupOfNames' DESC 'RFC2256: a group of
  names (DNs)' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST ( member $ cn ) MAY ( businessCategor
 y $ seeAlso $ owner $ ou $ o $ description ) )
olcObjectClasses: {8}( 2.5.6.10 NAME 'residentialPerson' DESC 'RFC2256: an r
 esidential person' SUP person STRUCTURAL MUST l MAY ( businessCategory $ x1
 21Address $ registeredAddress $ destinationIndicator $ preferredDeliveryMet
 hod $ telexNumber $ teletexTerminalIdentifier $ telephoneNumber $ internati
 onaliSDNNumber $ facsimileTelephoneNumber $ preferredDeliveryMethod $ stree
 t $ postOfficeBox $ postalCode $ postalAddress $ physicalDeliveryOfficeName
  $ st $ l ) )
olcObjectClasses: {9}( 2.5.6.11 NAME 'applicationProcess' DESC 'RFC2256: an
 application process' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST cn MAY ( seeAlso $ ou $ l $ de
 scription ) )
olcObjectClasses: {10}( 2.5.6.12 NAME 'applicationEntity' DESC 'RFC2256: an
 application entity' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST ( presentationAddress $ cn ) MA
 Y ( supportedApplicationContext $ seeAlso $ ou $ o $ l $ description ) )
olcObjectClasses: {11}( 2.5.6.13 NAME 'dSA' DESC 'RFC2256: a directory syste
 m agent (a server)' SUP applicationEntity STRUCTURAL MAY knowledgeInformati
 on )
olcObjectClasses: {12}( 2.5.6.14 NAME 'device' DESC 'RFC2256: a device' SUP
 top STRUCTURAL MUST cn MAY ( serialNumber $ seeAlso $ owner $ ou $ o $ l $
 description ) )
olcObjectClasses: {13}( 2.5.6.15 NAME 'strongAuthenticationUser' DESC 'RFC22
 56: a strong authentication user' SUP top AUXILIARY MUST userCertificate )
olcObjectClasses: {14}( 2.5.6.16 NAME 'certificationAuthority' DESC 'RFC2256
 : a certificate authority' SUP top AUXILIARY MUST ( authorityRevocationList
  $ certificateRevocationList $ cACertificate ) MAY crossCertificatePair )
olcObjectClasses: {15}( 2.5.6.17 NAME 'groupOfUniqueNames' DESC 'RFC2256: a
 group of unique names (DN and Unique Identifier)' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST (
  uniqueMember $ cn ) MAY ( businessCategory $ seeAlso $ owner $ ou $ o $ de
 scription ) )
olcObjectClasses: {16}( 2.5.6.18 NAME 'userSecurityInformation' DESC 'RFC225
 6: a user security information' SUP top AUXILIARY MAY ( supportedAlgorithms
  ) )
olcObjectClasses: {17}( 2.5.6.16.2 NAME 'certificationAuthority-V2' SUP cert
 ificationAuthority AUXILIARY MAY ( deltaRevocationList ) )
olcObjectClasses: {18}( 2.5.6.19 NAME 'cRLDistributionPoint' SUP top STRUCTU
 RAL MUST ( cn ) MAY ( certificateRevocationList $ authorityRevocationList $
  deltaRevocationList ) )
olcObjectClasses: {19}( 2.5.6.20 NAME 'dmd' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST ( dmdNam
 e ) MAY ( userPassword $ searchGuide $ seeAlso $ businessCategory $ x121Add
 ress $ registeredAddress $ destinationIndicator $ preferredDeliveryMethod $
  telexNumber $ teletexTerminalIdentifier $ telephoneNumber $ internationali
 SDNNumber $ facsimileTelephoneNumber $ street $ postOfficeBox $ postalCode
 $ postalAddress $ physicalDeliveryOfficeName $ st $ l $ description ) )
olcObjectClasses: {20}( 2.5.6.21 NAME 'pkiUser' DESC 'RFC2587: a PKI user' S
 UP top AUXILIARY MAY userCertificate )
olcObjectClasses: {21}( 2.5.6.22 NAME 'pkiCA' DESC 'RFC2587: PKI certificate
  authority' SUP top AUXILIARY MAY ( authorityRevocationList $ certificateRe
 vocationList $ cACertificate $ crossCertificatePair ) )
olcObjectClasses: {22}( 2.5.6.23 NAME 'deltaCRL' DESC 'RFC2587: PKI user' SU
 P top AUXILIARY MAY deltaRevocationList )
olcObjectClasses: {23}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.250.3.15 NAME 'labeledURIObject' DESC 'R
 FC2079: object that contains the URI attribute type' MAY ( labeledURI ) SUP
  top AUXILIARY )
olcObjectClasses: {24}( 0.9.2342.19200300.100.4.19 NAME 'simpleSecurityObjec
 t' DESC 'RFC1274: simple security object' SUP top AUXILIARY MUST userPasswo
 rd )
olcObjectClasses: {25}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.344 NAME 'dcObject' DESC 'RFC2247:
 domain component object' SUP top AUXILIARY MUST dc )
olcObjectClasses: {26}( 1.3.6.1.1.3.1 NAME 'uidObject' DESC 'RFC2377: uid ob
 ject' SUP top AUXILIARY MUST uid )
structuralObjectClass: olcSchemaConfig
entryUUID: 94005928-3521-1034-9edd-875b6f3874a7
creatorsName: cn=config
createTimestamp: 20150120185459Z
entryCSN: 20150120185459.719768Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=config
modifyTimestamp: 20150120185459Z

dn: cn={1}cosine,cn=schema,cn=config
objectClass: olcSchemaConfig
cn: {1}cosine
olcAttributeTypes: {0}( 0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.2 NAME 'textEncodedORAddress
 ' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.
 4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{256} )

<following olcAttributeTypes deleted to fit character limit>

olcObjectClasses: {0}( 0.9.2342.19200300.100.4.4 NAME ( 'pilotPerson' 'newPi
 lotPerson' ) SUP person STRUCTURAL MAY ( userid $ textEncodedORAddress $ rf
 c822Mailbox $ favouriteDrink $ roomNumber $ userClass $ homeTelephoneNumber
  $ homePostalAddress $ secretary $ personalTitle $ preferredDeliveryMethod
 $ businessCategory $ janetMailbox $ otherMailbox $ mobileTelephoneNumber $
 pagerTelephoneNumber $ organizationalStatus $ mailPreferenceOption $ person
 alSignature ) )
olcObjectClasses: {1}( 0.9.2342.19200300.100.4.5 NAME 'account' SUP top STRU
 CTURAL MUST userid MAY ( description $ seeAlso $ localityName $ organizatio
 nName $ organizationalUnitName $ host ) )
olcObjectClasses: {2}( 0.9.2342.19200300.100.4.6 NAME 'document' SUP top STR
 UCTURAL MUST documentIdentifier MAY ( commonName $ description $ seeAlso $
 localityName $ organizationName $ organizationalUnitName $ documentTitle $
 documentVersion $ documentAuthor $ documentLocation $ documentPublisher ) )
olcObjectClasses: {3}( 0.9.2342.19200300.100.4.7 NAME 'room' SUP top STRUCTU
 RAL MUST commonName MAY ( roomNumber $ description $ seeAlso $ telephoneNum
 ber ) )
olcObjectClasses: {4}( 0.9.2342.19200300.100.4.9 NAME 'documentSeries' SUP t
 op STRUCTURAL MUST commonName MAY ( description $ seeAlso $ telephonenumber
  $ localityName $ organizationName $ organizationalUnitName ) )
olcObjectClasses: {5}( 0.9.2342.19200300.100.4.13 NAME 'domain' SUP top STRU
 CTURAL MUST domainComponent MAY ( associatedName $ organizationName $ descr
 iption $ businessCategory $ seeAlso $ searchGuide $ userPassword $ locality
 Name $ stateOrProvinceName $ streetAddress $ physicalDeliveryOfficeName $ p
 ostalAddress $ postalCode $ postOfficeBox $ streetAddress $ facsimileTeleph
 oneNumber $ internationalISDNNumber $ telephoneNumber $ teletexTerminalIden
 tifier $ telexNumber $ preferredDeliveryMethod $ destinationIndicator $ reg
 isteredAddress $ x121Address ) )
olcObjectClasses: {6}( 0.9.2342.19200300.100.4.14 NAME 'RFC822localPart' SUP
  domain STRUCTURAL MAY ( commonName $ surname $ description $ seeAlso $ tel
 ephoneNumber $ physicalDeliveryOfficeName $ postalAddress $ postalCode $ po
 stOfficeBox $ streetAddress $ facsimileTelephoneNumber $ internationalISDNN
 umber $ telephoneNumber $ teletexTerminalIdentifier $ telexNumber $ preferr
 edDeliveryMethod $ destinationIndicator $ registeredAddress $ x121Address )
  )
olcObjectClasses: {7}( 0.9.2342.19200300.100.4.15 NAME 'dNSDomain' SUP domai
 n STRUCTURAL MAY ( ARecord $ MDRecord $ MXRecord $ NSRecord $ SOARecord $ C
 NAMERecord ) )
olcObjectClasses: {8}( 0.9.2342.19200300.100.4.17 NAME 'domainRelatedObject'
  DESC 'RFC1274: an object related to an domain' SUP top AUXILIARY MUST asso
 ciatedDomain )
olcObjectClasses: {9}( 0.9.2342.19200300.100.4.18 NAME 'friendlyCountry' SUP
  country STRUCTURAL MUST friendlyCountryName )
olcObjectClasses: {10}( 0.9.2342.19200300.100.4.20 NAME 'pilotOrganization'
 SUP ( organization $ organizationalUnit ) STRUCTURAL MAY buildingName )
olcObjectClasses: {11}( 0.9.2342.19200300.100.4.21 NAME 'pilotDSA' SUP dsa S
 TRUCTURAL MAY dSAQuality )
olcObjectClasses: {12}( 0.9.2342.19200300.100.4.22 NAME 'qualityLabelledData
 ' SUP top AUXILIARY MUST dsaQuality MAY ( subtreeMinimumQuality $ subtreeMa
 ximumQuality ) )
structuralObjectClass: olcSchemaConfig
entryUUID: 9400b986-3521-1034-9ede-875b6f3874a7
creatorsName: cn=config
createTimestamp: 20150120185459Z
entryCSN: 20150120185459.722234Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=config
modifyTimestamp: 20150120185459Z

dn: cn={2}nis,cn=schema,cn=config
objectClass: olcSchemaConfig
cn: {2}nis
olcAttributeTypes: {0}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.2 NAME 'gecos' DESC 'The GECOS field;
 the common name' EQUALITY caseIgnoreIA5Match SUBSTR caseIgnoreIA5Substrings
 Match SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {1}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.3 NAME 'homeDirectory' DESC 'The absol
 ute path to the home directory' EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4
 .1.1466.115.121.1.26 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {2}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.4 NAME 'loginShell' DESC 'The path to
 the login shell' EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121
 .1.26 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {3}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.5 NAME 'shadowLastChange' EQUALITY int
 egerMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {4}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.6 NAME 'shadowMin' EQUALITY integerMat
 ch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {5}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.7 NAME 'shadowMax' EQUALITY integerMat
 ch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {6}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.8 NAME 'shadowWarning' EQUALITY intege
 rMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {7}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.9 NAME 'shadowInactive' EQUALITY integ
 erMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {8}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.10 NAME 'shadowExpire' EQUALITY intege
 rMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {9}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.11 NAME 'shadowFlag' EQUALITY integerM
 atch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {10}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.12 NAME 'memberUid' EQUALITY caseExac
 tIA5Match SUBSTR caseExactIA5SubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.12
 1.1.26 )
olcAttributeTypes: {11}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.13 NAME 'memberNisNetgroup' EQUALITY
 caseExactIA5Match SUBSTR caseExactIA5SubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.146
 6.115.121.1.26 )
olcAttributeTypes: {12}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.14 NAME 'nisNetgroupTriple' DESC 'Net
 group triple' SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.1.1.0.0 )
olcAttributeTypes: {13}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.15 NAME 'ipServicePort' EQUALITY inte
 gerMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {14}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.16 NAME 'ipServiceProtocol' SUP name
 )
olcAttributeTypes: {15}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.17 NAME 'ipProtocolNumber' EQUALITY i
 ntegerMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {16}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.18 NAME 'oncRpcNumber' EQUALITY integ
 erMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {17}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.19 NAME 'ipHostNumber' DESC 'IP addre
 ss' EQUALITY caseIgnoreIA5Match SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26{128} )
olcAttributeTypes: {18}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.20 NAME 'ipNetworkNumber' DESC 'IP ne
 twork' EQUALITY caseIgnoreIA5Match SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26{128
 } SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {19}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.21 NAME 'ipNetmaskNumber' DESC 'IP ne
 tmask' EQUALITY caseIgnoreIA5Match SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26{128
 } SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {20}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.22 NAME 'macAddress' DESC 'MAC addres
 s' EQUALITY caseIgnoreIA5Match SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26{128} )
olcAttributeTypes: {21}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.23 NAME 'bootParameter' DESC 'rpc.boo
 tparamd parameter' SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.1.1.0.1 )
olcAttributeTypes: {22}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.24 NAME 'bootFile' DESC 'Boot image n
 ame' EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 )
olcAttributeTypes: {23}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.26 NAME 'nisMapName' SUP name )
olcAttributeTypes: {24}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.27 NAME 'nisMapEntry' EQUALITY caseEx
 actIA5Match SUBSTR caseExactIA5SubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.
 121.1.26{1024} SINGLE-VALUE )
olcObjectClasses: {0}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.0 NAME 'posixAccount' DESC 'Abstraction
  of an account with POSIX attributes' SUP top AUXILIARY MUST ( cn $ uid $ u
 idNumber $ gidNumber $ homeDirectory ) MAY ( userPassword $ loginShell $ ge
 cos $ description ) )
olcObjectClasses: {1}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.1 NAME 'shadowAccount' DESC 'Additional
  attributes for shadow passwords' SUP top AUXILIARY MUST uid MAY ( userPass
 word $ shadowLastChange $ shadowMin $ shadowMax $ shadowWarning $ shadowIna
 ctive $ shadowExpire $ shadowFlag $ description ) )
olcObjectClasses: {2}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.2 NAME 'posixGroup' DESC 'Abstraction o
 f a group of accounts' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST ( cn $ gidNumber ) MAY ( use
 rPassword $ memberUid $ description ) )
olcObjectClasses: {3}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.3 NAME 'ipService' DESC 'Abstraction an
  Internet Protocol service' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST ( cn $ ipServicePort $
 ipServiceProtocol ) MAY description )
olcObjectClasses: {4}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.4 NAME 'ipProtocol' DESC 'Abstraction o
 f an IP protocol' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST ( cn $ ipProtocolNumber $ descrip
 tion ) MAY description )
olcObjectClasses: {5}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.5 NAME 'oncRpc' DESC 'Abstraction of an
  ONC/RPC binding' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST ( cn $ oncRpcNumber $ description
  ) MAY description )
olcObjectClasses: {6}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.6 NAME 'ipHost' DESC 'Abstraction of a
 host, an IP device' SUP top AUXILIARY MUST ( cn $ ipHostNumber ) MAY ( l $
 description $ manager ) )
olcObjectClasses: {7}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.7 NAME 'ipNetwork' DESC 'Abstraction of
  an IP network' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST ( cn $ ipNetworkNumber ) MAY ( ipNe
 tmaskNumber $ l $ description $ manager ) )
olcObjectClasses: {8}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.8 NAME 'nisNetgroup' DESC 'Abstraction
 of a netgroup' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST cn MAY ( nisNetgroupTriple $ memberN
 isNetgroup $ description ) )
olcObjectClasses: {9}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.9 NAME 'nisMap' DESC 'A generic abstrac
 tion of a NIS map' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST nisMapName MAY description )
olcObjectClasses: {10}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.10 NAME 'nisObject' DESC 'An entry in
 a NIS map' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST ( cn $ nisMapEntry $ nisMapName ) MAY de
 scription )
olcObjectClasses: {11}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.11 NAME 'ieee802Device' DESC 'A device
  with a MAC address' SUP top AUXILIARY MAY macAddress )
olcObjectClasses: {12}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.12 NAME 'bootableDevice' DESC 'A devic
 e with boot parameters' SUP top AUXILIARY MAY ( bootFile $ bootParameter )
 )
structuralObjectClass: olcSchemaConfig
entryUUID: 9400f87e-3521-1034-9edf-875b6f3874a7
creatorsName: cn=config
createTimestamp: 20150120185459Z
entryCSN: 20150120185459.723847Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=config
modifyTimestamp: 20150120185459Z

dn: cn={3}inetorgperson,cn=schema,cn=config
objectClass: olcSchemaConfig
cn: {3}inetorgperson
olcAttributeTypes: {0}( 2.16.840.1.113730.3.1.1 NAME 'carLicense' DESC 'RFC2
 798: vehicle license or registration plate' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SUBSTR
  caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 )
olcAttributeTypes: {1}( 2.16.840.1.113730.3.1.2 NAME 'departmentNumber' DESC
  'RFC2798: identifies a department within an organization' EQUALITY caseIgn
 oreMatch SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1
 .15 )
olcAttributeTypes: {2}( 2.16.840.1.113730.3.1.241 NAME 'displayName' DESC 'R
 FC2798: preferred name to be used when displaying entries' EQUALITY caseIgn
 oreMatch SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1
 .15 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {3}( 2.16.840.1.113730.3.1.3 NAME 'employeeNumber' DESC '
 RFC2798: numerically identifies an employee within an organization' EQUALIT
 Y caseIgnoreMatch SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.
 115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {4}( 2.16.840.1.113730.3.1.4 NAME 'employeeType' DESC 'RF
 C2798: type of employment for a person' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SUBSTR cas
 eIgnoreSubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 )
olcAttributeTypes: {5}( 0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.60 NAME 'jpegPhoto' DESC 'RF
 C2798: a JPEG image' SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.28 )
olcAttributeTypes: {6}( 2.16.840.1.113730.3.1.39 NAME 'preferredLanguage' DE
 SC 'RFC2798: preferred written or spoken language for a person' EQUALITY ca
 seIgnoreMatch SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.
 121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {7}( 2.16.840.1.113730.3.1.40 NAME 'userSMIMECertificate'
  DESC 'RFC2798: PKCS#7 SignedData used to support S/MIME' SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.
 1.1466.115.121.1.5 )
olcAttributeTypes: {8}( 2.16.840.1.113730.3.1.216 NAME 'userPKCS12' DESC 'RF
 C2798: personal identity information, a PKCS #12 PFX' SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.14
 66.115.121.1.5 )
olcObjectClasses: {0}( 2.16.840.1.113730.3.2.2 NAME 'inetOrgPerson' DESC 'RF
 C2798: Internet Organizational Person' SUP organizationalPerson STRUCTURAL
 MAY ( audio $ businessCategory $ carLicense $ departmentNumber $ displayNam
 e $ employeeNumber $ employeeType $ givenName $ homePhone $ homePostalAddre
 ss $ initials $ jpegPhoto $ labeledURI $ mail $ manager $ mobile $ o $ page
 r $ photo $ roomNumber $ secretary $ uid $ userCertificate $ x500uniqueIden
 tifier $ preferredLanguage $ userSMIMECertificate $ userPKCS12 ) )
structuralObjectClass: olcSchemaConfig
entryUUID: 9401218c-3521-1034-9ee0-875b6f3874a7
creatorsName: cn=config
createTimestamp: 20150120185459Z
entryCSN: 20150120185459.724897Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=config
modifyTimestamp: 20150120185459Z

dn: olcBackend={0}mdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcBackendConfig
olcBackend: {0}mdb
structuralObjectClass: olcBackendConfig
entryUUID: 940161ce-3521-1034-9ee2-875b6f3874a7
creatorsName: cn=config
createTimestamp: 20150120185459Z
entryCSN: 20150120185459.726543Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=config
modifyTimestamp: 20150120185459Z

dn: olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcFrontendConfig
olcDatabase: {-1}frontend
olcAccess: {0}to * by dn.exact=gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=extern
 al,cn=auth manage by * break
olcAccess: {1}to dn.exact="" by * read
olcAccess: {2}to dn.base="cn=Subschema" by * read
olcSizeLimit: 500
structuralObjectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
entryUUID: 940022fa-3521-1034-9eda-875b6f3874a7
creatorsName: cn=config
createTimestamp: 20150120185459Z
entryCSN: 20150120185459.718381Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=config
modifyTimestamp: 20150120185459Z

dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
olcDatabase: {0}config
olcAccess: {0}to * by dn.exact=gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=extern
 al,cn=auth manage by * break
structuralObjectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
entryUUID: 940033e4-3521-1034-9edb-875b6f3874a7
creatorsName: cn=config
createTimestamp: 20150120185459Z
entryCSN: 20150120185459.718815Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=config
modifyTimestamp: 20150120185459Z

dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcMdbConfig
olcDatabase: {1}mdb
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap
olcSuffix: dc=yln,dc=info
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by self write by anonym
 ous auth by dn="cn=admin,dc=yln,dc=info" write by * none
olcAccess: {1}to dn.base="" by * read
olcAccess: {2}to * by self write by dn="cn=admin,dc=yln,dc=info" write by *
 read
olcLastMod: TRUE
olcRootDN: cn=admin,dc=yln,dc=info
olcRootPW:: <password hash>
olcDbCheckpoint: 512 30
olcDbConfig: {0}set_cachesize 0 2097152 0
olcDbConfig: {1}set_lk_max_objects 1500
olcDbConfig: {2}set_lk_max_locks 1500
olcDbConfig: {3}set_lk_max_lockers 1500
olcDbIndex: objectClass eq
structuralObjectClass: olcMdbConfig
entryUUID: 94016bce-3521-1034-9ee3-875b6f3874a7
creatorsName: cn=config
createTimestamp: 20150120185459Z
entryCSN: 20150120185459.726800Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=config
modifyTimestamp: 20150120185459Z
```

Admittedly, most of this is Greek to me so I don't know what to do to troubleshoot. What might I try next? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using OpenLDAP 2.5.13 from https://ltb-project.org/documentation/index.html on CentOS 8 stream, I'm able to get your LDIF to load with the following changes:

1. I commented out all of the path-related configurations from `cn=config`
   because they didn't apply on my system, and I didn't want to bother
   setting up certificates:

   ```
   #olcArgsFile: /var/run/openldap/slapd.args
   #olcPidFile: /var/run/openldap/slapd.pid
   #olcTLSCACertificatePath: /etc/openldap/certs
   #olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/openldap/certs/1d40117d24e9b169.pem
   #olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/openldap/certs/yln.key
   ```
2. I need to explicitly load the `back_mdb` module:

   ```
   dn: cn=module,cn=config
   objectClass: olcModuleList
   cn: module
   olcModulePath: /usr/local/openldap/libexec/openldap/
   olcModuleLoad: back_mdb.so
   ```

   This may not be necessary if it has been compiled into your local
   build.
3. I replaced all of the schemas with the appropriate content from my
   local `openldap/schemas/` directory.
4. I fixed a syntax error in one of your olcAccess rules. You had:

   ```
   olcAccess: {2}to * by self write by dn="cn=admin,dc=yln,dc=info" write by *
    read
   ```

   It looks as if you dropped a trailing space ( ) there at some
   point; as written, that unfolds to:

   ```
   olcAccess: {2}to * by self write by dn="cn=admin,dc=yln,dc=info" write by *read
   ```

   Where that `*read` on the end is invalid syntax. You can either
   just add a trailing space after `*`, or better yet reformat the
   line to be a little more readable:

   ```
   olcAccess: {2}to *
     by self write
     by dn="cn=admin,dc=yln,dc=info" write
     by * read
   ```

   Note that each line is indented *two* spaces. This gets us one
   space for the LDIF folding, and then another literal space to
   separate each line from the last word on the preceding line.
5. I had to comment out all of the `olcDbConfig` statements, which
   were unrecognized in my environment:

   ```
   #olcDbConfig: {0}set_cachesize 0 2097152 0
   #olcDbConfig: {1}set_lk_max_objects 1500
   #olcDbConfig: {2}set_lk_max_locks 1500
   #olcDbConfig: {3}set_lk_max_lockers 1500
   ```

With this changes, I was able to successfully `slapadd ...` your
content.

Comment: You can see my complete test [here](https://github.com/larsks/so-example-716344/tree/main).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I don't have a /usr/local/openldap directory so I'm guessing that's part of the problem. Shouldn't that have been installed when I compiled OpenLDAP?

Comment: No. I have a `/usr/local/openldap` directory because that's where the packages I'm using are configured to store things by default. Your build will be configured differently. The primary problem was probably the syntax error (item (4) above) in your ACL configuration.

Comment: There was a space after the * but I formatted it as you suggested and I still got the same error when I do slapadd.

I found the path to back_mdb.so and substituted it. Now I get the error
`config_back_db_open: No explicit ACL for back-config configured. Using hardcoded default`
`loaded module back_mdb.so`
`module back_mdb.so: null module registered`
`<= str2entry: str2ad(olcDbConfig): attribute type undefined`
`slapadd: could not parse entry (line=656)`

Comment: Line 656 is this:
`dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config`

Comment: That seems to be complaining about the `olcDbConfig` entries, which as I said I had to comment out.

Comment: I commented the olcDBConfig entries out as well which got me past that error. Now I have the problem that the directory `/var/run/openldap` doesn't exist so it can't write slapd.args or slapd.pid. I copied over the directory and files from the old server which seemed to slapadd happy, but when I reboot, the directory disappears again so I can't start slapd. I can't find anything on the web to fix this and there are no errors beyond the fact that the pid file can't be written. Any ideas?

Comment: `/var/run` is typically a symlink to `/run`, which is an ephemeral directory. You can create a directory structure there automatically at boot with an appropriate configuration in [`/etc/tmpfiles.d`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service.html)...or just remove `olcPidFile` and `olcArgsFile`, which generally aren't necessary.

Comment: I commented out those two lines, cleaned up everything, and slapadded the config again. I confirmed that nothing in the slapd.d directory contains a pid path. When I restart slapd, I get `slapd.service: Can't open PID file /var/lib/openldap/slapd.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory`. I'm assuming that it's also supposed to be writing a pid file there. The directory openldap is owned by ldap:ldap and permissions are 755. I don't understand what's failing here.